# Tube preamp overdrive question

Tags: audio, preamp, distortion, tube

Is it possible to add an overdrive gain pot (instead of just simply a bypass switch) to a preamp tube circuit?

I am designing a new amplifier, and I want to include an overdrive/distortion option to the preamp section, but I want it to be incorporated via a pot to add the overdrive/distortion into the main signal.  Not like a clean/dirty channel.  This amplifier is not for guitar purposes, but keyboard purposes.  I am looking at examples like the Soldano SLO-100 that uses an overdrive channel that gets mixed with the clean channel via a kill overdrive switch.  Is it possible to use a pot where the switch is such that it can be dialed in from zero to full?

Comment: The term you might be looking for is a mixer. The reason why overdrive switches were used is that they physically changed the amplifier's gain at the front-end to produce a lot of distortion hence you couldn't have the presence of a clean and dirty sound simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You just need to a balance control that goes between 100% clean and 100% dirty. It's not quite like a stereo balance control, you need a dual gang pot, one gang for each side, and sum the two outputs, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm92He.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

decoupling caps, rolloff cap etc omitted for clarity. Be sure to wire the pot so that when one is at max level, the other is at zero - otherwise you made a volume control! The value of 1k8 for the summing resistor will load the 10k linear pot so that it gives a decent enough approximation of a log law. This is desirable as linear pots are more reliable than log ones (and maybe cheaper too).

You could also have two separate 10k pots and mix the two signals that way. Choose your poison.

By the way you can get a pretty decent emulation of a tube amp "soft asymmetrical clipping" using a low value zener with a series resistor as the distortion element. If you want to know how that sounds, it is in the box being shown on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5eV0XcUiOs). (Shameless plug for my own design, but in context I think.)

Comment: Ahh, nice!  I was thinking it was more sophisticated!  Thank you so much for responding to my question.

Comment: you're welcome. Please upvote and mark as "the answer" if this is what you needed. good luck with your project!

Comment: Ok, now you got my interest.  I have also heard about using zeners to clip the signal.  but again, im using this for keyboard purposes, and i want to have a dialed level of orverdrive.  do you have a solution for adding this zener approach with a pot from zero distortion to full distortion (whatever the full amount of distortion is set to)?

Comment: @MikeHale please note my comment above.

Comment: @MikeHale https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers